# Which directory do we write in React

Tags: reactjs

I've installed Node.js on my pc, but where do I write my JS?
Is it in the default folder or do I've to make a new one?

Here below you see my React folder:

```
12-10-2019  11:09    <DIR>          .
12-10-2019  11:09    <DIR>          ..
26-10-1985  10:15               310 .gitignore
12-10-2019  11:09    <DIR>          build
12-10-2019  11:04    <DIR>          node_modules
12-10-2019  11:03           524.508 package-lock.json
12-10-2019  11:03               621 package.json
12-10-2019  11:03    <DIR>          public
26-10-1985  10:15             2.891 README.md
12-10-2019  11:03    <DIR>          src
           4 File(s)        528.330 bytes
           6 Dir(s)  903.737.974.784 bytes free
```

Thanks for helping,
Valdemar Vreeman

Comment: look in `src` and there should be an `index.js` file there.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source folder is generally where programmers code reside for best practices except you need to configure somethings that you choose to use the other folders 
So you start adding code to the `src` folder

Comment: But if there is a new version and you update it, would it not overwrite your code?

Comment: No it won't updates will only take place in the configuration files and settings for the framework

Comment: Oh okay and my last question is: I've downloaded React, but after I refresh the localhost:3000, it looks like it breaks the site or something else

Comment: What do you mean by it breaks can you describe what exactly happens?

Comment: I mean, I change the code in VS Code(no problem in there) and after I refresh the site, the error 'site not available' appears.

Comment: Did you shot down the server that was running at port 3000, You need to run `npm start` and don't shut it down unless you want to terminate the app

Comment: Okay and now I see some errors, maybe because I have shut down the server. But how do I avoid that?

Comment: You need to start the server and don't shut it down while you are working(coding) or running the application  react comes with watchman that will automatically refresh your browser when you edit your code an save it.

Comment: No Its already available the moment you created the project. You can test it out by first running the project and then you edit something  you will notice it automatically refreshes in your browser

Comment: So I don't have to worry about the refresh in the browser?

Comment: Yes it's just an advantage to you as the developer that it will speed up your work. but you don't have anything to worry about for now.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for helping me! Í apprechiate your help. And I going to fix the errors.